# @Override compile error, implementing an interface (eclipse jre7 Windows)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting compile errors in eclipse when using the @Override annotation for a class that is implementing an interface.

JDK compliance level is set to 1.7.

I am using the latest version of the jdk7.

Error: "The method {methodname} of type {classname} must override a superclass method"

```html
public interface DataDictionary {
 
 public Map<String, ? > getAllEntries(String dictionaryName);
 ...
        ...

}


public class StringDictionary implements DataDictionary {

        @Override // this generates the error
 public Map<String, ?> getAllEntries(String dictionaryName) {

  // some implementation

  return dataDictEntries;

 }
```

Comment: You're not overriding properly. That's all we can say.

Comment: Related code would make it much easier to work on an answer that would be useful.

Comment: I am implementing an interface and the project is working perfectly as intended. Only when I add @Override annotation it gives an error.

Comment: Does your superclass has method with same signature that you are overriding?Could you please post your code?

Comment: Are you sure `Map` refers to the same type in the interface and the class that implements it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think have solved it. Earlier I was only modifying the workspace properties only but using maven project with SVN. Maven was internally setting property of each project to use "Project Specific 1.5 java compliance" at each update.

I changed each project to use workspace JDK compliance and removed project specific settings in SVN projects to prevent from future errors after code update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then remove the method deceleration in your subclass(StringDictionary ) then compiler will ask you to implement unimplemented method in super class. then with the help of eclipse you use option `Add unimplemented method`.

Hope so it will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that but when Eclipse adds unimplemented methods it doesn't add '@Override'

Comment: @ArihantBanthia I think it is your eclipse issue not java issue, better to try any other eclipse version?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried exactly your code - no problem at all. JDK1.6 should be sufficient, as `@Override` for interfaces was added in JDK1.6. From all I can see in the question, your code is correct and should work fine.

I suggest things like restart Eclipse or change the method then change it back, it seems something inside Eclipse got out of sync with your code.

Comment: I compiled the entire code in JDK 1.6 it is fine.
But when I recompile the code using JDK 1.7 it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion ,delete the class file eclipse has generated for you,make some edits(like comments) to the file,save and let eclipse build again for you.